# Is there a better way to get the index of max value of a List created by lambdas function

Tags: java, lambda

I have an int array of hours representing the 24 hours in a day.
For each hours i have an int that represent the affluences on this hours.

I'm trying to figure out what are the busiestTwoHours of a Day

```
private int this.hoursCounts = new int[24];
```

I need to use primitve datatype but i can convert it in method

So i convert my primitive in array into a list like that.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(this.hourCounts).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now i add for each hour affluences of next hour to get an array

Beginning of two hours => Affluence of this two hours

```
List<Integer> list2 = IntStream.range(0,  list.size())
            .filter(i -> i < list.size() - 1)
            .boxed()
            .map((i) -> list.get(i) + list.get(i + 1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But i can't find a way to return index of busiests two hour in one line i need to create a new List to do what i want. So i compute index by computing max value with reduce with my new list...

```
 int index = IntStream.range(0, list2.size())
            .reduce((last, current) -> list2.get(last) > list2.get(current) ? last : current)
            .getAsInt();
```

Can i do this in one line and without creating new List ?
i need to use only lambda !
Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Why exactly are you creating `list2`?

Comment: list2 is just list where i have added next element value in tab[0]  += tab[1]

Comment: This will honestly be much easier and more readable if you don't use streams and don't try to squeeze it all into one line, and just do a for loop.

Comment: I know but the main purpose of my course was to do this specific task with lambdas